# jQuery doesn't removing class before .each function

Tags: jquery, each

I got small problem with my script.

The script looks like it works, but each time it adds the selected class. It resets it before the onclick, but the class does not remove it. What could be a problem?

Only one element of the .payment class from the collection should have a .selected class

```js
$(".payment").each(function() { 
    $(".payment").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).on("click", function() { 
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

```css
.selected { 
background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> example
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> of my
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> problem
</div>
```

Comment: sauero  did you want all radio button checked? or only that one who is clicked ? if you want second-one then check my answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were removing the `selected` class only on the beginning. I assume you want it to be removed every time a checkbox is checked as does the code below.

```js
$(".payment").each(function() { 

   $(this).on("click", function() { 
   $(".payment").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

```css
.selected { 
background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> example
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> of my
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" /> problem
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Mistakes such as these are easily made.

Comment: @sauero  did you see that all three radio buttons are checked through this code, whih is incorrect. Check my answer for correct solution

Comment: You dont need any `each` to make this.

Comment: @sauero  did you checked what i said in comment. All radio-buttons are in checked mode. Is it what you want? or you want one raido button at-a-time will be selected as well as checked too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should modify your code to avoid multiple event bindings. It's not a good practice to bind events in a loop.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".payment", function() {
            $(".payment.selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2237/

Answer (score 0):

Remove class from all `.payment` and add class for current element:

```js
$(".payment").on("click", function() { 
    $(".payment").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true)
});
```

```css
.selected { 
background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/> example
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/> of my
</div>

<div class="payment">
 <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/> problem
</div>
```